# User identification privacy

Tags: support, privacy

I have noticed that every month or so when I check my profile, the site has automatically filled in my real name. I assume it is stripping the information from my email address.

I do not want my name stored on StackExchange servers, regardless of whether or not it is "private."

Is there some way to get rid of this bug/"feature"? It would be much appreciated.

Comment: I haven't observed that behaviour so far, and I previously used a mail address containing my full name here. I'd guess that you're using Facebook or something similar as your OpenID login and the information is coming from there. As a related point, the full name field in your profile is only visible to mods, not to any other users.

Comment: Yes, I am using Yahoo to log in. As for my name's visibility, I don't want other users, mods, or even admins, to have my real name. I don't want it anywhere in your database if it doesn't absolutely have to be. I certainly do not mean to insult the security of the website or the integrity of the moderators, but I think I have a reasonable right to try to keep my real name offline. I hope people agree.

Comment: I suddenly feel long for the internet to return to how it was 15 years ago...

Comment: @Asaf, according to your profile, 15 years ago, you were 11 years old. You were an early bloomer!

Comment: @Gerry: You should check my profile in three days, and yes I was an early boomer. I was the first  (or second) in my class with internet at the mind boggling speed of 28.8kbps which disconnected every 60 minutes.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you don't want your name passed to StackExchange, then you should not have clicked the button that allowed the credentials to be passed from your OpenID provider (whom I assume has your real name) to StackExchange.

See [this article](http://evan.prodromou.name/OpenID_Privacy_Concerns) for a discussion. I quote

> First, it's important to be cognizant of this data-sharing model -- that once you've shared the data, it's out the door and into the wild world, and there's not much you can do to get it locked back up. If that worries you, be really conservative with what data you share.

With that said: if you don't want your name associated, you can either

- Remove the real name from your OpenID provider. The next time you log-in the new credentials will have no real name field.
- Register for a separate anonymous OpenID account and use that for StackExchange. What you should do is to click on the "my logins" link in your profile, add the new OpenID account to it, and [remove the old one](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22223/how-do-i-remove-an-openid-or-login).

Comment: Thank you for this! I didn't know OpenID allowed for anonymous accounts (without email, I mean). It was surprisingly simple to remove all my other logins.

Comment: Great answer - we do pull Real Name directly from what an OpenID provider sends us.

Comment: Also note that if you're using a Google/Gmail provider, we **demand** email, so if one chooses not to send email, the login process will terminate.